# Unexpected token issue with jsx files React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So I just initialized a React Native project the other day and was trying to configure my eslint and for some reason I get an `unexpected token <` error on the return for my stateless JSX component.

```
import React from 'react';

const User = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Text>
        Hello!
      </Text>
    </>
  );
};

export default User
```

I am extending the default `@react-native-community` that the eslintrc file is initialized with.
As another note I was trying to use the airbnb eslint configuration and that causes the unexpected token error on both js and jsx files at the same location. I was wondering if anyone knew the reason as to why I am getting this error. Thanks in advance for the help!

Fixed: As stated below my fix ended up being to install babel-eslint and set my parser to babel-eslint in the eslintrc file.

Comment: It can be that the linters are not recognizing the short syntax for Fragments ```<>```.
Try using ```<React.Fragment>```.

Comment: Have tried using any element. Still didnt work. I tried to putting a Text element in there solo and it still yelled at me.

Comment: [try this](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/447)

Comment: The above link by humanbean worked for me! I installed babel-eslint and set my parser to babel-eslint inside the eslintrc and it fixed everything. Thanks!

Comment: As from the above link, adding `parser: 'babel-eslint'` solved this for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import React.

```
import React from 'react   
const User = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Text>
        Hello!
      </Text>
    </>
  );
};

export default User
```

Comment: I did have that in the file. Just forgot to copy it over.